# Reg-ex, Find x then N characters if N+1 == x

Tags: regex, string, split

OK here is what I have:

```
(24(?:(?!24).)*)
```

its works in the fact it finds from 24 till the next 24 but not the 2nd 24... (wow some logic).

---

like this:

```
    23252882240013152986400000006090000000787865670000004524232528822400513152986240013152986543530000452400
```

---

it finds from the 1st 24 till the next 24 but does not include it, so the strings it finds are:

```
    23252882 - 2400131529864000000060900000007878656700000045 - 2423252882 - 2400513152986 - 24001315298654353000045 - 2400
```

that is half of what I want it to do, what I need it to find is this:

```
    23252882 - 2400131529864000000060900000007878656700000045 - 2423252882240051315298624001315298654353000045 - 2400
```

lets say:

```
x = 24
n = 46
```

I need to:

```
find x then n characters if the n+1 character == x
```

so find the start take then next 46, and the 45th must be the start of the next string, including all 24's in that string.

hope this is clear.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
   answer = 24.{44}(?=24)
```

Comment: Which regex dialect are you using?  And what do you want to happen if you count 46 characters and the next is not `24`?

Comment: If the next is not 24 do nothing, as for what regex the .NET one [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.

First, find `x` (24):

```
24
```

Then, find `n`=46 characters, where the 46 **includes** the original 24 (hence 44 left):

```
.{44}
```

The following character *must* be `x` (24):

```
(?=24)
```

All together:

```
24.{44}(?=24)
```

You can play around with it [here](http://regexr.com?30sj0).

In terms of constructing such a regex from a given `x`, `n`, your regex consists of

```
x.{n-number_of_characters(x)}(?=x)
```

where you substitute in `x` as-is and calculate `n-number_of_characters(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
(?(?=24)(.{46})|(.{25})(.{24}))
```

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
(?(?=24)(.{46})|(.{25})(.{24}))

Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Do a test and then proceed with one of two options depending on the result of the text «(?(?=24)(.{46})|(.{25})(.{24}))»
   Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=24)»
      Match the characters “24” literally «24»
   If the test succeeded, match the regular expression below «(.{46})»
      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.{46})»
         Match any single character that is not a line break character «.{46}»
            Exactly 46 times «{46}»
   If the test failed, match the regular expression below if the test succeeded «(.{25})(.{24})»
      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(.{25})»
         Match any single character that is not a line break character «.{25}»
            Exactly 25 times «{25}»
      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(.{24})»
         Match any single character that is not a line break character «.{24}»
            Exactly 24 times «{24}»
-->
```